# Software for symbolic quantum mechanical commutators

Tags: symbolic-algebra

Is there any symbolic computer software for commutators of tensor products of different kinds of operators?

For example for `qubits and bosons`, I need to be able to simplify commutators of operators of the form

$$ Q \otimes a $$.

where `Q` can be any pauli operator and `a` is a bosonic ladder operator that only satisfies the canonical commutation relation

$$ [a,a^\Dagger]=1 $$.

Please can someone help me format the math